# Zipp lists in python by iterating through a list of lists

Tags: python-2.7, list, izip

I have two lists of lists as follows. To merge them, I usually do the following:

```
>>>from itertools import imap, ilist

>>>a = [1,2,3]
>>>b = [4,5,6]
>>> c = list(imap(list,izip(a,b)))
>>> c 
[[1, 4]], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

However, now I have a list of list as follows:

```
[[1,2,3], 
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9],
]
```

How do I iterate through each list and pass it to the izip function to obtain the following output:

```
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

Comment: Where does the last row of the list of lists come from? Maybe clarify the input a little.

Comment: Yes..if that makes it clearer

Comment: the point is that there can be n number of rows..i want to iterate through through each row and get the final output as shown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer for edited Question:

```
>>> input_list=[[1,2,3], 
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9],
]
```

Using map and zip:

```
>>> map(list,zip(*input_list))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Using imap and izip:

```
>>> list(imap(list,list(izip(*input_list))))
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer for previous question:

By using list comprehension and two for loops:

```
input_list =[[[1],[2],[3]], 
 [[4],[5],[6]],
 [[7],[8],[9]],
]


out_list = [[] for i in range(len(input_list))]
for each_row in input_list:
    for i in range(len(each_row)):
        out_list[i].extend(each_row[i])
print out_list
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: ..i have edited my question by simplifying the input..can you modify your answer for it please ?

Comment: Added the answer @Amistad

Answer (score 0):

I think u need something like this:

```
input_list =[[1,2,3], 
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9],
        ]
result = []

for i in range(len(input_list)):
   temp = []
   for list in input_list:
      temp.append(list[i])
   result.append(temp)
print result
```

result will be:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```